# Image cropped inside div. How to maintain original aspect

Tags: html, css, image

I am editing a websites original theme, and have presently run into an image that is cropped vertically inside a div
See codepen or example below: https://codepen.io/hioioasd90/pen/LzvmpW

I would like for this image to display in its entirety, but be scaled to the outside containers set width.
After editing the chrome console, changing `height: 27vh;` to a larger number will result in the image showing more inside the div, however it beings to go beyond the boundaries of the max width.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;

}

.img-cover-category {
    background: none no-repeat center center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 27vh;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="img-cover-category" style="background-image: url(https://writernikhilpro01.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/unsplash-laptop-desk.jpg);"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible with background-size: cover; it's possible with background-size: contain; but the used image needs to be at least 1000px wide, in your case of course. I'd rather suggest the img tag solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you would like to achieve, first you could delete doubled:

```
background-size: cover; // this is doubled in the css code
```

and add:

```
background-size: contain; // new version for every browser
```

And from this point try to adjust the size of the image.

Here is what you can delete:

```
.img-cover-category {
    background: none no-repeat center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 27vh;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

And paste this instead:

```
.img-cover-category {
    background: none no-repeat center;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 27vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Then if the scaling should leave the image fixed to the top and not center in the middle you can change this:

```
 background: none no-repeat top;
```

**ADJUSTMENT TO NEW SITUATION vesrion A**

Instead of adjusting height of the image set a height of the container

```
.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.img-cover-category {
   background: none no-repeat top;
   -moz-background-size: contain;
   -o-background-size: contain;
   -webkit-background-size: contain;
   background-size: contain;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%; /* Currently this seems to be obsolete */
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Also adding **min-height: lets say 1000px to the .img-cover-category** seems make the background visible aswell...

To be honest I don't know what this will be a header, a background - maybe you could add a normal image instead of background.... if you want it to be visible all the time...

Comment: Whilst this resizes the image it is now extremly small. 
What would need to be changed so it can have the maximum height possible starting from the top left, whilst keeping the same aspect ratio inside the div?

Comment: I saw your new version, and you already changed the size... If you want to start from top, left than maybe you could delete margin: 0 auto from .container in css.... or set it manually to top, left

Comment: That was due to changing height: 27vh, until it hit the maximum width. However if I decide to use another image I will need to adjust it manually. Which I would rather it be done automatically

Comment: Actually you need to remember it is not an image but a background image - so the key here is the content or size of the div... That is confusing... The height of the div should be either set or contain something so the background can be shown - this is what I think at least.  I updeted another solution - some minor changes but height of the container was set.